# how to load an image from the url getting from server

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, swift4, imageurl

I am having and imageView and I am getting the userData from the server when loggedIn in the userData I have a parameter for "profilePic":"penguins.jpg". now I am adding the domain like "http://.....(self.userData.value(forKey: "profilePic")!)" and saving this value into a string variable to store and when I am accessing the value and trying to convert the url into data and adding to imageView.image it is throwing : unexpectedly  found nil while unwrapping an optional value..

All my other userData like name,address,phoneNumber are showing fine except for Image.

My Code:

here are the some of the many ways I tried:

way:1

```
let ad : AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

let imageUrlString = ad.userImagePath
let imageUrl:URL = URL(string: imageUrlString)! // it is throwing error here(: unexpectedly  found nil while unwrapping an optional value)

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {

    let imageData:NSData = NSData(contentsOf: imageUrl)!

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
        self.profileImage.image = image
    }
}
```

way:2

```
if let url = NSURL(string: ad.userImagePath) {
            if let data = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL){
                if let imageUrl = UIImage(data: data as Data) {
                    profileImage.image = imageUrl
                }
            }
        }
```

I have tried different ways to solve this, can't figure out what is my mistake.. finally I am here.. Please someone help he...

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-downloading-image-from-url-on-swift ?

Comment: Because of `"profilePic":"penguins.jpg"` as mean your `imageUrlString` is `penguins.jpg`. That's a string, not url, so it will return nil

Comment: @Quoc Nguyen I am doing "let imageUrl:URL = URL(string: imageUrlString)!" to convert it into url... so, it should convert right???

Comment: @VenkateshChejarla : You want to download the `penguins.jpg` to your app or your app has it before

Comment: @Quoc Nguyen : I want to download the image..

Comment: @VenkateshChejarla: You must to ask your server return the image as in a url link, not image name. The response should be "profilePic":"https://www.example.com/penguins.jpg"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading/Downloading image from URL on Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-downloading-image-from-url-on-swift)

Comment: @Quoc Nguyen : you can see my question just updated I am adding the that string to the "profilePic" in the dictionary by                                             ad.userImagePath = "http://domainName.com/app/Users/ProfilePics(self.userData.value(forKey: "profilePic")!)"

Comment: @VenkateshChejarla try this `ad.userImagePath = "domainName.com/app/Users/ProfilePics" + "\(self.userData.string(forKey: "profilePic")!)" `

Comment: @Quoc Nguyen : I am getting error saying "value of type NSDictionary has no member string"...

Comment: @Quoc Nguyen : And I think there is no need to use + for concatenation as I am doing it right..or I think so..

Comment: @VenkateshChejarla : Dont force unwrap the `self.userData.string(forKey: "profilePic")`. Check it. If it return nil, that mean you has not save it before. Let save it. The next time you can get it

Comment: @Quoc Nguyen : mate you don't get it... it is throwing error saying there is no such property "string" for type NSDictionary. So, this `self.userData.string(forKey:"profilePic")` and that is like wrong syntax.. I am using swift 4. May be that is the reason